# Activating sub-menu links after e.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to turn my css dropdown menu into a touch enabled menu when on devices that support it. The problem I am having is that I have the parent li's behavior stopped using e.preventDefault() and I cant seem to figure out how to get the children li's to function as normal. Here is the code I am using:

```
if ("ontouchstart" in window || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints) {
    $('#menu > li:has(ul.sub-menu)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#menu > li > a.sub-menu').toggle(300);
        $('#menu > li > ul > li > a').trigger('click');
    })
}
```

The functionality of keeping the main li from going through and toggling the sub-menu works perfectly. I now just need the sub-menu a to go through when clicked.

Comment: what is the purpose of `$('#menu > li > ul > li > a').trigger('click');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop the propagation from those anchor elements

```
if ("ontouchstart" in window || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints) {
    $('#menu > li:has(ul.sub-menu)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#menu > li > a.sub-menu').toggle(300);
        $('#menu > li > ul > li > a').trigger('click');
    })
    $('#menu ul.sub-menu a').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    })
}
```

Comment: The purpose of the trigger line is the activate the link on click. Should that be removed?

Comment: what do you mean by activate the link? also whether stopping the propagation solves your problem

Comment: allow the link to be followed. Yes the stop Propagation works but I want to know if I need the trigger line?